# jmeter how to use json path extractor

Tags: jmeter

I'm new to jmeter.
I want to save the value of the key in a variable, if the id is `7106` from the following response

```
[{"id":"MAIN","key":1},
{"id":"87","city":"Roselle","key":1000,"state":"IL"},
{"id":"7102","city":"Chicago","key":110,"state":"IL"},
{"id":"7106","city":"Crown Point","key":110038,"state":"IN"},
{"id":"7108","city":"Indianapolis","key":1139,"state":"NJ"}]
```

How to do it in jmeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some options:

Option 1: [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

[image]

Option 2: [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor)

[image]

Option 3: [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! It really helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add post Processor - JSON Extractor to your sampler and create a variable of any name, in JSON Path expression give value = $..key , this should extract all values that "key" holds.

Now add View Result Tree to see all variables created, suppose you give variable name as "key" , all values should be stored as key_1, Key_2 and so on..

you can use any value now, as in your case it would be ${key_4} . Adding picture for your help

[JSON Extractor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyGxZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use [JSON JMESPath extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) which allows executing arbitrary [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) queries, in your case it would be a [Filter Expression](https://jmespath.org/proposals/filter-expressions.html) like:

```
[? id=='7106'].key
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [The JMeter JSON JMESPath Extractor and Assertion: A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide)